# How to parse txtfile and export into dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, text-parsing

My task is to parse a txtfile and return a dictionary with the counts of last names in the file. The txtfile looks like this:

```
city: Aberdeen
state: Washington
Johnson,    Danny
Williams, Steve
Miller,    Austin
Jones, Davis
Miller,    Thomas
Johnson, Michael
```

I know how to read the file in, and assign the file to a list or a string, however I have no clue how to go about finding the counts of each and putting them into a dictionary. Could one of you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the HOMEWORK tag to your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

with open('test.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

reobj = re.compile("(.+),", re.MULTILINE)
dic = {}
for match in reobj.finditer(text):
    surname = match.group()
    if surname in dic:
        dic[surname] += 1
    else:
        dic[surname] = 1
```

The result is:

```
{'Williams,': 1, 'Jones,': 1, 'Miller,': 2, 'Johnson,': 2}
```

Comment: Can you explain

reobj = re.compile("(.+),", re.MULTILINE)

and

surname = match.group(), specifically group()? I've done reading on regular expressions however the patterns used still allude me.

Comment: This regex `(.+),` matches all strings that end with a comma, as this seemed the easiest way to parse out the surnames from the given file format.  We execute the regex then iterate through each match.  `match.group()` just returns the matched string.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikey. You've done your country a great service.

Comment: I have one more question, maybe you could answer it before I accept it as the answer? In nitin's reply, he has the line "if lastnames.has_key(last)". I can't get this to work because has_key doesn't exist as a method. Why is this?

Comment: Forget that, I figured it out. Thanks again Mikey!

Comment: According to the docs "has_key() is deprecated in favor of key in d." http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the counts of each surname:

- you need to create a dictionary, empty will do
- loop through the lines in the file
- for each line in the file determine what you need to do with the data, there appear to be headers. Perhaps testing for the presence of a particular character in the string will suffice.
- for each line with that you decide is a name, you need to split or perhaps partition the string to extract the surname.
- then using the surname as a key to the dictionary, check for and set or increment an integer as the key's value.
- after you've looped through the file data, you should have a dictionary keyed by surname and values being the number of appearances.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re
    file = open('data.txt','r')
    lastnames={}
    for line in file:
        if re.search(':',line) ==None:
            line.strip()
            last = line.split(',')[0].strip()
            first = line.split(',')[1].strip()
            if lastnames.has_key(last):
                lastnames[last]+= 1
            else:
                lastnames[last]= 1
    print lastnames
```

Gives me the following

```
>>> {'Jones': 1, 'Miller': 2, 'Williams': 1, 'Johnson': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach. No need to use regex. Also filtering blank lines for extra robustness.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from collections import defaultdict

def nonblank_lines(f):
    for l in f:
        line = l.rstrip()
        if line:
            yield line

with open('text.txt') as text:
    lines = nonblank_lines(text)
    name_lines = (l for l in lines if not ':' in l)    

    surnames = (line.split(',')[0].strip() for line in name_lines)

    counter = defaultdict(int)
    for surname in surnames:
        counter[surname] += 1

    print counter
```

If you're using a Python version > `2.7` you could use the built in [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) instead of a `defaultdict`.